# How to access Build Number in the powershell script

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have a power shell script which gets triggered from the Microsoft Release management tool. when I say NewRelease the pop up comes which will ask me to select the Build Drop Number in a dialog. After I select the latest or a particular build drop number how do I access in my power shell script ?

I tired using the variable BuildNumber but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a vNext release template on RM Update 4, you don't have easy access to variables.

For Deployer-based release templates, you can use the `$(BuildNumber)` variable, but be aware that this **only** works when passed as an argument to a **component**. Using it in a regular action will not work.